# hi i am writing a c program to get the position of a character in a given string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am developing a code to return a position of a character in string. 
I have removed all the error but when I run the program my compiler
crashes.

> find a position in a given string

```
// int str_find_char(char *str, char *ch) - 
// returns the position where ch is in str and if not present returns -1
#include <stdio.h>

char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
char d;
int str_find_char(char (*ptr),char *chr)
  {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
       {
         printf("h");
       }
  }

int main(void)
 {
   char (*ptr)[5];
   char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
   ptr = &arr;
   int i,k=0;
   char *chr;
   char ch;
   chr = &ch;
   printf("enter the value to search = ");
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   str_find_char( (*ptr), chr);

   if(*(ptr[i]) = ch)
     {
      printf("element found at = %d",i);
      k = 1;
     }
    else if(k == 1)
      {
        printf("element found at = %d",i);
        return 0;
      }
    else {
      return -1;
      }

}
```

Comment: `ch` isn't in the string, `*ch` could very well be.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything.

Comment: Nor is it doing anything with the parameters you give it.

Comment: Also please play with your compiler switches - that code very much ought to spit out a truckload of warnings!

Comment: `str_find_char()` simple prints `"hhhhh"`.  It does not attempt to find `ch` nor does it return a value.

Comment: @chux I know people like this :)

Comment: `if(*(ptr[i]) = ch)` assigns `ch` to `*(ptr[i])`.  Likely this is not the desire goal.  Perhaps `==` to compare?

Comment: The chracter array `char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};` is not a _string_ as it lacks a null character.  Suggest changing to `char arr[] = "abcde";` or ``char arr[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e', '\0'};`` if the goal remains "to get the position of a character in a given string".  Otherwise, change to something like  "to get the position of a character in a character array"  This would add clarity to the post.

Comment: If your compiler crashes, then reinstall it.  That has nothing to do with errors in your program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you said you search in a string that means it must be null terminated.

You can change

```
char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
```

to

```
char arr[] = "abcde";
```

and use the code below

```
int GetCharPos(char* str, char ch)
{
   int i = 0;
   int ret = -1;

   while(*str){

      if(*str++ == ch){

         ret = i;
         break;
      }

      i++;
   }

   return ret ;
}
```

Note that this code will work only if you pass a null terminated string.

Comment: Apparently, in the given OP code the input is not a null-terminated string.

Comment: @martin it will not work in the example given as passed table is not a string

Comment: @martin and if not found it will always return some >= number.

Comment: Posting how to use this `GetCharPos()` is a successful and not successful case would add clarity.

Comment: @PeterJ eem he said " return a position of a character in string"

Comment: All C _strings_ are null character terminated, else they are not strings.  OP's goal "to get the position of a character in a given string" is unfortunately not well reflect with test code as it is not using a string.

Comment: @martin still does not work with OPs `char arr[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};` it is not null terminated

Comment: @PeterJ as i said earlier he said " return a position of a character in string" so it's not my mistake he doesn't know a string must be null terminated

Answer (score -1):

*Annti Haapala* is right. Your compiler should be generating truckloads of warnings, among which should also be a few errors.

You should repeatedly check if you've found a matching character

```
int str_find_char(const char* str, char ch){
    const char* p = str;
    for(;*p;p++)
        if(*p== ch)
            return (p - str);
    return -1;
}
```

...and as a good practice, use a const pointer if the function does not change the string.

Also notice UBs:

```
int i,k=0; // i is uninitialized
char *chr;
char ch;
chr = &ch;
printf("enter the value to search = ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
str_find_char( (*ptr), chr);

if(*(ptr[i]) = ch) // Use an uninitialized variable?
  { // Now exit with Segmentation fault!
```

Comment: Simply function and two return points - not a good coding practice

Comment: @PeterJ No bad style. This can well avoid calling an extra function, `strlen`.

Comment: It is - in more complex it is a source of a very hard to find errors and it is very hard to read. What for this pointer arithmetic?

Comment: and very interesting assignment `char* p = str;` where str is `const char *`